# Substring result of for-each loop

Tags: xslt, foreach

I have a below `for-each` loop in my XSLT which gives me concatenated string of distinct values of `CUST_PO_NUMBER` from input XML

```
<xsl:key name="custpo"
         match="LIST_G_DELV/G_DELV/LIST_G_INV_LINES/G_INV_LINES"
         use="CUST_PO_NUMBER"/>
<xsl:template match="XXFIN_GBL_RAINV_PRINT">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="LIST_G_INV"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="LIST_G_INV">
    <xsl:for-each select="G_INV">
        <xsl:value-of select="CUSTOMER_TRX_ID"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(LIST_G_SEB/G_SEB/SEB_NAME,1,255)"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(IDM_BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_NAME,1,255)"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_NUMBER"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="TRX_NUMBER"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="LIST_G_DELV/G_DELV/LIST_G_INV_LINES/G_INV_LINES[generate-id()=generate-id(key('custpo',CUST_PO_NUMBER)[1])]">
            <xsl:value-of select="CUST_PO_NUMBER"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="CUST_ISO_LANGUAGE"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Ultimately output of this XSLT is CSV file (seperated by pipe | ). Can we just truncate result of for-each loop on CUST_PO_NUMBER element to 1000 characters?

Comment: As JLRishe suggested in his answer, you can solve the problem using a variable and `substring()`. However, if the string that is compiled from those elements is by far longer than 1000 characters (let's say 100,000) before cutting it to the appropriate length, then maybe it's more efficient to use a recursive approach where you check whether you're under 1000 characters on each recursion. However, if the string is usually not so much longer (say 10,000), I'd expect the recursive approach to be slower. I'm not 100% sure about this, though, so it would have to be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work if you replace the following `for-each`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="LIST_G_DELV/G_DELV/LIST_G_INV_LINES/G_INV_LINES[generate-id()=generate-id(key('custpo',CUST_PO_NUMBER)[1])]">
        <xsl:value-of select="CUST_PO_NUMBER"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

with:

```
 <xsl:variable name="values">
    <xsl:for-each select="LIST_G_DELV/G_DELV/LIST_G_INV_LINES/G_INV_LINES[generate-id()=generate-id(key('custpo',CUST_PO_NUMBER)[1])]">
        <xsl:value-of select="CUST_PO_NUMBER"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:value-of select="substring($values, 1, 1000)" />
```

and since you'd be using a `substring()` anyway, you can eliminate the `if` and `text` by doing this:

```
 <xsl:variable name="values">
    <xsl:for-each select="LIST_G_DELV/G_DELV/LIST_G_INV_LINES/G_INV_LINES[generate-id()=generate-id(key('custpo',CUST_PO_NUMBER)[1])]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(';', CUST_PO_NUMBER)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:value-of select="substring($values, 2, 1001)" />
```

Comment: Hi JLRishe, Your suggestion is quite good. However I did a mistake while posing the question. The XSLT I pasted was simplified. Actually there are more elements in the TEMPLATE along with CUST_PO_NUMBER and they all form a single string (each loop represent a line in CSV file). Ultimately output of this XSLT is CSV file (seperated by pipe | ). With suggested approach each line in CSV will be trunctaed to 1000 characters, correct? Can we just truncate result of for-each loop on CUST_PO_NUMBER element?